# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException Could not find a part of the path 'C:\home\site\Temp\filename.msi'

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller

I am building MVC project and a part of the logic is to save file (received as byte[]) to specific folder. It works in debug on my PC and it doesn't work when publish to Azure.

Here is my code:

```
var uniqueFileName = $"MSI{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.msi";    
var pathToWriteFile = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, @"..\TempFolder\" + uniqueFileName);

File.WriteAllBytes(pathToWriteFile , file);
```

What is my mistake and why it works in debug and doesn't work in Azure!

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `Path.GetTempPath()` to get a usable temp directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=net-6.0&tabs=windows

Comment: @rhughes How it work with Azure? Will it be accessible from cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Posibly you can't acces the parent directory on the prod server

Comment: Why? And how can I change it?

Comment: Let's say you are deploying your project (www.myproject.my) 'phisically' over 'C:/inetpub/www/myproject/' so with the 
Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, @"..\TempFolder\"
You're trying to acces to C:/inetpub/www/TempFolder, that is forbbiden, and .
Try using a Temp Folder INSIDE your project
Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "TempFolder", ...

Comment: Actually, temp folder placed inside the project

Comment: so, why are you referencing to ..\TempFolder\ in the path combine?
remove the two leading dots and the backslash
As sidenote: including \ , / in path combine is a risky business if you change from deploying over an iis to an Linux machine